# Using Regex to the number of twitter mentions in Spark (Scala)

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark. I want to output the top 2 twitter mentions using this test.txt file:

"I love to dance @Kelsey, especially with you @Kelsey!"

"Can't believe you went to @harvard. Come on man @harvard"

"I love @harvard"

Essentially, multiple mentions in a single tweet only counts once. So the output would be like:

```
(2, @harvard)

(1, @Kelsey)
```

So far, my codes looks like the following:

```
val tweets = sc.textFile("testFile")

val myReg = """(?<=@)([\\w]+)""".r

val mentions = tweets.filter(x => (myReg.pattern.matcher(x).matches))
```

However, it would not work because x is still a line and it will not match as a result. Is there anyway I can test the word in the line instead of the line itself? Also, how do I check if that mention is redundant in the tweet?

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your regex a little and you might need to translate it back to spark syntax, but this way you find all mentions and group them. The `.toSet` is important to remove duplicates, `.toLowercase` would also make sense there

```
  val tweets = List("I love to dance @Kelsey, especially with you @Kelsey!",
                "Can't believe you went to @harvard. Come on man @harvard",
                "I love @harvard")


  val myReg = """(@\w+)""".r

  val mentions = tweets.flatMap(x => myReg.findAllIn(x).toSet).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)

  println(mentions)
```

Comment: groupBy is an expensive operation in spark. better use reduceByKey see my answer

Answer (score 0):

That works for me, the regexs is more tweeter exact

```
val myReg = "(^|[^@\\w])@(\\w{1,15})\\b".r

val mentions = tweets.flatMap(x => myReg.findAllIn(x).matchData.map(_.group(0).trim -> 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I upvoted your answer but for some reason stackoverflow is not showing my upvote

Comment: @Ragnall_Mac_Somairle you should accept it if you believe its the right answer

Comment: Hey @Noam Shaish . How should I change the regex if I want to strip punctuation before and after mention? For example, I want "!@Kelsey" = "@Kelsey!" = "@Kelsey"